# Transmission Remote GUI setup hangs on DHT attempting to bootstrap

Tags: gui, transmission

I'm trying to install transmission on Ubuntu Server 12.04. But I'm running into few issues, The main one now is that the setup seems to hang on:

```
DHT Attempting bootstrap from dht.transmissionbt.com (tr-dht.c:247)
```

Here is the guide I have followed: [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/setting-up-transmission-remote-gui-in.html).

Installing the transmission daemon went fine, But when I tried to configuring it, It gave me the above issue.

The command is: `transmission-daemon -f -t -u your_username -v your_password -w /path/to/downloaded/torrents -g /etc/transmission-daemon/`

At first I used '&' symbol in the password and that messed some things up. I restarted the server and then used the same command with a password without '&' it goes through.
The command does hang for a while on the  line

```
transmission-daemon requiring authentication (daemon.c:508)
```

but then after say 20 seconds or so, It goes on to the line

```
DHT Attempting bootstrap from dht.transmissionbt.com (tr-dht.c:247)
```

It hangs there for over 10 min. The next line should be something about starting port forwarding.

When I look for the files that the command should have created, They look fine, Username is set, Not sure where to find the password though.

Still I cannot continue, And if I quit the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, when I run the remote GUI, It doesn't connect (it doesn't say more than that).

Any idea what is wrong? Any idea on how to go about figuring this out?

Sidenote: when running `transmission-daemon -f -t -u your_username -v your_password -w /path/to/downloaded/torrents -g /etc/transmission-daemon/` for the first time, it said it failed to allocate the correct size to something UDP, and said to edit a file to specify the larger size. I did so, rebooted, and that issue was gone once re-trying.

Not sure if this helps but this is what comes after executing the command:

```
[22:31:21.566] Transmission 2.51 (13280) started (session.c:718)

[22:31:21.567] RPC Server Adding address to whitelist: * (rpc-server.c:803)

[22:31:21.567] RPC Server Serving RPC and Web requests on port 127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/ (rpc-server.c:997)

[22:31:21.568] RPC Server Whitelist enabled (rpc-server.c:1001)

[22:31:21.568] RPC Server Password required (rpc-server.c:1004)

[22:31:21.568] Port Forwarding Stopped (port-forwarding.c:181)

[22:31:21.569] DHT Generating new id (tr-dht.c:309)

[22:31:21.569] Using settings from "/etc/transmission-daemon/" (daemon.c:488)

[22:31:21.569] Saved "/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json" (bencode.c:1731)

[22:31:21.570] transmission-daemon requiring authentication (daemon.c:508)

[22:32:13.576] DHT Attempting bootstrap from dht.transmissionbt.com (tr-dht.c:247)

^C

[22:57:39.319] Saved "/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json" (bencode.c:1731)

[22:57:39.320] DHT Saving 67 (67 + 0) nodes (tr-dht.c:366)

[22:57:39.320] Saved "/etc/transmission-daemon//dht.dat" (bencode.c:1731)

[22:57:39.321] Port Forwarding Stopped (port-forwarding.c:181)

Closing transmission session... done.
```

Comment: also, when doing `sudo service transmission-daemon restart` the command errors our with `Couldn't read "/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json": Permission denied`

Answer (score 3):

Just had this one myself and it is fixed easily by changing ownership of the file:

```
sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json
```

This got me back and running right now. You can also try changing the user and group to `root:debian-transmission` if the previous doesn't work.